# How to insert selected Grid Checkbox to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

I have a grid which contain checkbox. We managed to get the All ChecksRecord correctly using GetCheckProduct() function, the question is how to pass to the controller selected product from GetCheckProduct()  when the AddSelectedProduct clicked.

Here is the code so far. Thank you

```
<script>
      var getCheckProduct = function () {
        var grid = $('#Product').data().kendoGrid;
        var elem = grid.element;
        var data = $('#Product').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data();
        var count = 0;
        var res = [];
        var checkbox = elem.find(".chkbx").each(function () {
            var t = $(this);
            if (t.is(":checked")) {
                res.push(data[count].TRN);
            }
            count += 1;
        });
        return res;
    };

      $("#AddSelectedProduct").on("click", function () {




        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@(Url.Content("~/ProdDetails/AddSelectedProduct/"))',
            data: {

                "selectedProduct": getCheckProduct()



            }
        });
        return false;
    });


</script>
```

The problem is the selectedProduct is not pass to the controller.

```
Controller:
public ActionResult AddSelectedConsumer(string[] selectedProduct, Guid ReferralListID)
        {
            UpdateConsumer(selectedProduct);

            return Json(null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to either stringify your data using `JSON.stringify([getCheckProduct())`:

```
 $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
      url: '@(Url.Content("~/ProdDetails/AddSelectedProduct/"))',
      datatype: "json",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: JSON.stringify([getCheckProduct())              
 });
```

or set the `traditional` option of your ajax request to true:

```
 $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
      url: '@(Url.Content("~/ProdDetails/AddSelectedProduct/"))',
      datatype: "json",
      traditional: true,
      data: { 'selectedProduct': getCheckProduct() }              
 });
```

However, your controller action also has a second parameter, so depending on your configuration, it may not get called if that isn't in the data you send.